# What's the reason for having conditional expressions and not loop expressions?

Tags: java, programming-languages

I'm using Java 6.

Do you think there's a reason why there are conditional expressions

```
String plan = ( isEconomyGood() ? "find a job" : "stay with mom" ) ;
```

and not loop expressions

```
weeklyPlan.add( schedule.hasNext() => schedule.next() );
```

which adds elements from schedule into weeklyPlan while `hasNext()`.

Or do some languages have this feature or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because conditional expressions are much easier to implement without having to worry about pesky details. For example, looking at your code, are you saying that weeklyPlan.add will be called multiple times? In that case, the scope of your `=>` operator just jumped outside of the parentheses that contain it.

C# has features in LINQ that can perform similar actions to what you're describing. It implements these using closures and extension methods:

```
schedule.AsParallel().ForAll(s => weeklyPlan.add(s));
```

But these are much more tricky language constructs than Java started out with and the .NET runtime has been able to change much more rapidly than the Java platform has, largely for political reasons. Java 7 was supposed to feature closures, but they got pushed back to the "next version."

Answer (score 3):

These "loop expressions", in a slightly different form, are called [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29). In groovy-code:

```
schedule.each() {
   weeklyPlan.add(it)
}
```

That is - you can define what happens with each object of the `schedule` collection.

Java does not yet support closures. There it is implemented with anonymous classes.

Of course closures are more than that, and this is only one of their applications.

Answer (score 0):

Because the designers wanted to keep the language simple. A lot of the ugly stuff in Java comes from importing constructs in from other languages to ease the transition for developers to shift to Java (from C++ in particular). The ternary operator is a good example of this. (The handling of primitives is another, more controversial, case)

Until the introduction of generics in 1.5, 'textbook' Java code would have had a very simple and consistent syntax. Even anonymous inner classes, the trickiest pre-1.5 constructs, are pretty easy to grok given half an hour.